# Multiplication of sequences and equivalence relations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, equivalence-relations, rational-numbers

The following is from my lecture notes (trying to understand).

Let $(q_n)$ and $(r_n)$ be two sequences of rational numbers. Let $X=\{(q_n)\in \mathbb{Q}: \forall\varepsilon\in \mathbb{Q}^+, \exists n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N} \mbox{ such that } |q_n-q_m|<\varepsilon \mbox{ for } n,m\ge n_\varepsilon\}$, that is $X$ is a set of Cauchy sequences of rationals.

Define an equivalent relation ~ on $X$ as follows:

$(q_n) \sim (r_n)$ if $\forall\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+, \exists n_\varepsilon\in \mathbb{N} \mbox { such that } |q_n-r_n|<\varepsilon \mbox{ whenever } n\ge n_\varepsilon$.

Now define

$$t_n=     \begin{cases} 
      1 & r_n = 0 \\
      1/r_n & \mbox{otherwise} \\
         \end{cases}$$

Then $(r_n)(t_n) \sim (1,1,\dots)$.

The part I don't get is how it can be possible that $(r_n)(t_n) \sim (1,1,\dots)$. For if $r_n=0$ then $(r_n)(t_n)=0$. Take $\varepsilon = 1/2$ and the $\sim$ does not hold.

Would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing part of your notes? Before "Now define" there should've been something about the sequence $(r_n)$ -- it should've been introduced or defined in some way.

Comment: @zipirovich No $(r_n)$ is just an arbitrary rational sequence.

Comment: And I'm guessing $(r_n)(t_n)$ means component-wise multiplication, right? Then it's not true exactly for the reason you stated. The simplest example: if $r_n=0$ for all $n$, i.e. $(r_n)=(0,0,\ldots)$ is the constant zero sequence, then $(r_n)\in X$, $(t_n)=(1,1,\ldots)$ is the constant sequence of all ones, and $(r_n)(t_n)=(0,0,\ldots)\not\sim(1,1,\ldots)$. That's why there has got to be some condition that separates $(r_n)$ away from zero.

Comment: I think the condition is that $(r_n)$ has finitely many repeating zeros. But I don't think this helps anyway.

Comment: Finitely many zeroes would help. Then $n_\epsilon$ values all start after that.